# To get input date from user in batch file

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I am trying to run a SQL Query through Batch File and when I am trying to do so I am getting

> invalid argument error

Below is the batch file with which I am trying to run my SQL SCRIPT

```
:start

cls

@echo ------BILLING REPORT---------

@echo Please enter billing report Date in (YYYY/MM/DD)

@echo off 

::set /P D = Enter Date:  

::Date %Date% > Billing_Data.sql

PAUSE

sqlcmd -S database\instance_name -E -i "C:\Users\rb54761\Deskto\rb54761\Billing_Data_For_Certs_New.sql" > Output.txt -v Date = '2016-07-01'

:: -o "C:\Users\rb54761\Desktop\rb54761\Output.txt"

PAUSE

COPY C:\Users\rb54761\Desktop\rb54761\Output.txt C:\Users\rb54761\Desktop
PAUSE

goto start
```

for this i need to thing
1. when user input the date, data will fetch according to that date
2. i want to add that date in where clause so that data will fetch accordingly
Below is the where clause where i want to enter the data

```
WHERE
DateCompleted > CONVERT(DATETIME, '$(Date)', 102))
```

Comment: It's not SQL it batch! And ` > Output.txt -v Date = '2016-07-01'` in a batch file does not cut it! Redirection must not be followed by arguments. Try to set `echo on` to find where the error lies. But it's at least where I pointed out.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server database\instance_name, Line 28
Incorrect syntax near '2016'.
i am thinking the error is while converting Date in SQL file it is not accepting full date instead it is only using 2016.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - Not true. File redirection can appear anywhere within a command - at the front, at the end, or in the middle! The subsequent arguments in the OP's command are arguments to sqlcmd, not the redirection.

Comment: @dbenham- then why I am hgetting the error? it should take whole date instead of 2016

Comment: i resolved the issue but there is a new issue whenever i am inputting the date through

SET \p D = Enter Date:

then i am getting all the data instead of mentioned date

Comment: @dbenham thanks at least I learned something today :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you command line you use `-v Date = '2016-07-01'`, and the single quotes are considered part of the sqlcmd variable. In your script you use `'$(Date)'`, which becomes `''2016-07-01''`, and the error should be fairly obvious.

Remove one set of quotes from either the command line or the script, and all should work.

If you want to quote the value in the command line to protect against poison characters or to include batch token delimiters like space or comma, then you must use double quotes: something like
`-v var = "Some value with spaces"`. In this case, the double quotes are **not** included in the value.

Comment: i checked that and error is resolved but now the issue is as i mention in my previous comment that i can't get specific output instead of that i am getting whole table in my output file if i am trying to use SET \p D = Enter date and in sqlcmd -v Date = "%D%"

Comment: `set \p` ? I suppose you mean `set /P`